# What is the Islamic position on torture of prisoners?

Tags: sharia, torture

Different states in the world often use torture both physical and psychological for interrogation, suppressing political opponents etc. What does Islam say about use of torture by state actors? Would it be allowed for an Islamic state to use torture as a method for interrogation?

And what does the Quran say about it?

Comment: What kinds of torture? It's not a very clear term, some countries might classify telling a Jewish prisoner he's been fed pork torture, others won't call it torture until bones crack.

Comment: Do you consider being whipped 1000 times as a form of torture ? It seems rather unpleasant.

Comment: @user5751924 read the question again. I have specified that "use torture both physical and psychological for interrogation, suppressing political opponents" And i am not aware of any punishment about 1000 lashes in Islam.

Comment: https://abdurrahman.org/2014/01/31/prisonerofbadr/